# Using Workflow to Set Reorder point

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I have a work flow that executes on a saved search
      - Items whose "reorder point" are "empty"
The action sets the field "reorder point" to zero

However when i look into the item record, the reorder point is still empty.
when i look at the system notes, it shows that the workflow set the reorder point to 0. However, the field is still showing "empty"

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the correct field and you don't have a duplicate name anywhere? That's happened to me before.

Comment: Yes its the only field "reorderpoint" in our environment.